# How to setup SVN server on a VPS with Centos 6.2 and WHM already installed

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, centos, vps, whm

Background:
Managed VPS (hosted by KnownHost), with WHM/Cpanel on Centos 6.2.
I'm attempting to setup a SVN server to help my gave dev team keep revisions of code and other assets.

I've had the host support install subversion, however I'm having a heck of a time getting WedDav to work (the url for the users to use TortoiseSVN).

Is there a step by step tutorial on how to setup SVN on CentOS 6x server with WHM installed?

I've googled and searched Stackoverflow, but the tutorials or sites I find only cover SVN on CentOS, not with WHM.  The reason of course I need something that takes into account WHM as there are some apache changes when WHM is installed and then of course I get lost as I'm a newbie to linux administration (however I do pick things up quickly if explained and don't mind making attempts on my own).

I've reached out to Knownhost support, but they don't make promises on '3rd party' software.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you want to be able to access Subversion via Apache http using the `http://` protocol? Is that correct?

There's an on line [Subversion manual](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/) which gives you step-by-step instructions on setting up [Apache http](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html) to act as your Subversion repository server.

The trick isn't necessarily the configuration files. The trick is getting all the http modules and a correct version of Subversion that works with HTTP. Fortunately, most pre-compiled command line clients now work with HTTP. (That wasn't always the case). However, you have to make sure that Apache httpd is built correctly.

You can find the Apache httpd modules under `/etc/httpd/modules`. Make sure `mod_dav_svn.so` and `mod_dav.so` are both there. If not, you might have to rebuild Apache httpd. If you are using your Windows Active Directory for authentication, you'll have to make sure that `mod_ldap.so` and `authzn_ldap.so` are also included. You can find [LDAP configuration here](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialApacheAddingLoginSiteProtection.html#LDAP).

The configuration will be under `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` and under `/etc/httpd/conf.d/subversion.conf`. The idea is to keep the Subversion configuration in a separate file. Note that if you use LDAP, you may be exposing a password in the configuration. You may need to modify the permissions and ownership to prevent users from finding the account information and the password associated with the account. Otherwise, you may want to use a special account that can only read the LDAP directory, but has no access to the repository itself.

You'll still need to use `svnadmin create` to create the actual repository. Again, see the Subverison on line manual for more information.

Comment: Thank you for providing a direct link to setting up httpd for apache for SVN.  It has been like pulling teeth trying to get Apache compiled for mod_dav_svn.. however the KnownHost support finally got it installed last night.   Hopefull I can just follow those step by step instructions now and be ok.

Answer (score 0):

If I may,

Under Centos6 it may appear you do NOT need to rebuild anything.  This is on a fresh kickstart of c6:

```
# rpm -qf /etc/issue     # works for everything but suse
centos-release-6-6.el6.centos.12.2.x86_64
# yum install mod_dav_svn mod_authnz_pam subversion -y

::::::::::::::
/etc/httpd/conf.d/v000.prequel.conf
::::::::::::::
NameVirtualHost *:80

::::::::::::::
/etc/httpd/conf.d/v555_virt_svn.conf
::::::::::::::
<virtualhost _default_:80>
  Servername     svn.corp.com
  serveralias    svn

  Alias     /svn    /data/svn

  <Directory /data/svn>
    Authtype        basic
    AuthName        "Subversion (AD)"
    AuthBasicProvider   PAM
    AuthPamService  system-auth
    Require     valid-user
    #Option     +Indexes
  </Directory>
</Virtualhost>

::::::::::::::
/etc/httpd/conf.d/v999.default.conf
::::::::::::::
<virtualhost _default_:80>
Servername      localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

I'm pretty close to where I want it, but I'm thinking I'm a little past where you are here, and I've not done something as foolish as hand-building software for an enterprise OS that I would then need to support.  ;-)